# Using factory function parameters as editable private variables

Tags: javascript

I want to pass some values to a factory function that I intent to keep as private variables. Is it a bad practice to edit the function parameters like this?

```js
factory (name, age) {
  const editAge = (newAge) => {
    age = newAge;
  }
  const editName = (new Name) => {
    name = newName;
  }
  return { editAge, editName }
}
```

is this okay or should I return the name & age variable as properties of the returned object?
Like this:

```js
return {name, age, editAge, editName }
```

Comment: I would consider it bad practice to overwrite the parameters. Why not use internal variables?

Comment: Why don't you use a class? That seems to be what you're emulating.

Comment: If they should be private, then you shouldn't return an object that makes them accessible to the caller.

Comment: @evolutionxbox as in assigning name and age value to internal private variables? That didn't cross my mind. Thank you.

Comment: @Sandeep https://medium.com/@Rahulx1/revealing-module-pattern-tips-e3442d4e352 may help?

Comment: "*or should I return the name & age variable as properties of the returned object?*" if you don't return them, then what actual purpose do they serve? The code never exposes them, nor ever reads them. Only sets them, yet if they are never read, then it matters little what or *if* you set them. But most of all, as Barmar said, you probably should use a class. Or at the very least an old style constructor function (yet I don't see any advantage it has over classes). A function that constructs an *object* has its place - that's a data constructor. Yet the data object wouldn't have setters.

Comment: @VLAZ one advantage it had, until recently, is that classes didn't have private methods.

Comment: @Barmar while learning JS, i.e. not too long ago, I've read much about preferring factories over classes, so I thought I'd use factory for the personal project I'm currently working on.

Comment: @VLAZ I should apologise for not mentioning there are methods to access the values as well. I just didn't put it here.

Comment: @evolutionxbox [trivial problem to solve](https://jsbin.com/lutaguheko/edit?js,console). Close it in a module, export the class only and presto - private fields, methods, whatever you want. Note that it's not even much different from a regular function which *also* doesn't have private methods. Only inner scoped ones.

Comment: @VLAZ indeed. When RMP was in major use, WeakMap didn't exist either.

Comment: @evolutionxbox a problem I have with using RMP is that i want create multiple objects dynamically. So I guess using a class is the best choice here.

Comment: "*is this okay*" - maybe. "*…or should I return the name & age variable as properties of the returned object?*" - what does that have to do with modifying the parameters?